# Use AD credentials to log into Samba DC

Tags: active-directory, samba, samba4

We have a Samba domain controller for our active directory. We want to set it up such that in order to log into it, you use your Samba credentials, just like non-DC boxes connected to the domain. However, I can't find any real documentation on how to do this. What do I need to do to set this up?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to use the Samba domain controller to authenticate logins to your boxes? In that case, you need to either join your boxes to the domain or set up PAM and sssd.conf to authenticate via AD and use the Samba machine as the ldap server.

Comment: @NasirRiley We already do that. I want to use the Samba domain controller to authenticate logins to the Samba domain controller.

Comment: Then all you need to do is set it up to authenticate in the same way that the other machines do. I'm surprised it isn't already set up like that.